# ElastAlert and libmagic

Tags: elastalert, python-magic

When trying to run ElastAlert via python (per ElastAlert read the docs page) the below is returned.

Command:

```
python -m elastalert.elastalert --verbose --rule example_frequency.yaml
```

Error:

```
ImportError: failed to find libmagic.  Check your installation
```

I have tried a pip uninstall and reinstall of python-magic 0.4.15 (version which is required of ElastAlert) and still get the same error.